# Running two threads [c]

Tags: c, multithreading

I need to run two separate processes simultaneously. One is just listening on port X, and sends data when it receives sth, the second one is doing some other stuff.

Ive tried this:
`pthread_t thread1, thread2;`
`int  iret1, iret2;`

`iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, getAddress(), NULL);`

`iret2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, operate(), (struct IPlist) *IPlist);`

In the first one I would like to run `get(Address)` - the listening and sending part, in the second one I need to run `operate()` with one arg: `*IP list //(struct IPlist *IPlist)`

BUT, it shows errors:

`warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ makes pointer from integer without a cast`
`/usr/include/pthread.h:225: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type int`

`error: incompatible type for argument 4 of ‘pthread_create’`
`/usr/include/pthread.h:225: note: expected ‘void * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘struct IPlist’`

What is wrong here?

I do not really understand the manual, so I am asking here.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: What is it that you're asking? There's no question in the text above.

Comment: @Shaggy can you please tell us what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Wait, you haven'y asked anything yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `getAddress` and `operate` instead of `getAddress()` and `operate()` when calling `pthread_create`. You have to supply `functions` instead of their return values.

You also need to supply your data to these threads through the last argument. It should go like this:

```
struct IPlist *IPlist;
iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, getAddress, IPlist);
iret2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, operate, IPlist);
```

And your functions should be like:

```
void* getAddress(void* data) { struct IPlist *IPlist = data ; /* ... */ }
void* operate(void* data) { struct IPlist *IPlist = data ; /* ... */ }
```

If your program keeps stalling, be sure to check out [`pthread_mutex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/pthread.h.html) objects.

Comment: thanks, ive done that, but still: `iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, getAddress, HERE)`  what should i write instead of `HERE`? `void *getAddress() {...`

Comment: @shaggy - check the new answer.

Comment: great! but, i want to run `getAddress` without any parameter/arg, how to achieve that?

Comment: btw, in the second case `operate()` results in error, two few args. even in case i remove `()`

Answer (score 1):

```
I think you should pass address of function.

struct IPlist *IPlist;
iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, (void *) &getAddress, (void *)IPlist);
iret2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, (void *) &operate, (void *)IPlist);

assuming that function decleration is 

 - void getAddress (void *)

 and 

 - void operate (void *)
```

.